# Finding a number where the tangent line at a point is parallel to line drawn through endpoints?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Problem:$f(x)=6x^2+4x$. What is the number c in the interval $[0,4]$ such that the line tangent to the graph of $f(x)$ at point $x=c$ is parallel to the line drawn through the endpoints of the interval?

Attempt: I started by taking the derivative of $f(x)$, which is $12x+4$ but I am not sure of what steps to take from here. Do I plug the endpoints back into the parent function or set the derivative equal to another equation...If anyone can help, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: what are the coordinates of (0,f(0)) and (4,f(4))?  What's the slope of the line between those two points?

Comment: Have you been taught application of derivatives and any mean value theorems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First find the function evaluated at 0 => f(a) and then find the function evaluated at 4 => f(b)
Then take and get f’(c) and that’s function evaluated at 4 - the function evaluated at 0 over 4-0
(F(b)-f(a))/(b-a)).  This is the Mean value theorem MVT for short it’s an application of the derivative. Also => is implies. Shorthand notation I used to clarify.

Comment: Thank you, just getting acquainted with the Mean Value Theorem! I got 28 to be the resulting value for f’(c) but how do I get the tangent line to be parallel to the line containing the endpoints? I was a bit confused by this part of the problem...

Comment: F(c) = 28 so take your derivative and set it equal to 28 so it’s 12x + 4 = 28... 12x = 24 and X i= C so C is equal to 2. The point C that is parallel to the line should be 2. Do you happen to know the answer to verify my thoughts? Cause not much else can be done with the information that I can think of...

Comment: I believe 2 is the correct answer! Thank you so so much :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Lagrange's mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem).